# How to call the return () in functional component react environment after fetching and procesing api data?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, return, use-effect, core-ui

```
 * eslint-disable react/display-name */
  import React, { useEffect } from "react";
  import axios from "axios";
  import TableLayout from "../../reusable/TableLayout";

  const Platforms = () => {

  let usersData = [];
  let platform_data;

  useEffect(() => {

     const getData = async () => {
     const getPlData = await getPlatformData();
     createPlatformArray(getPlData);

  };

  getData();

  // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

  }, []);



    const getPlatformData = async () => {

      if (JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loginData"))) {

          let access_token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("loginData")).access_token;



         let config = {
           method: "get",
           url: "api_url",
           headers: {
             Authorization: "xxxxx",
           },
         };           


         platform_data = await axios(config)
                      .then(function (response) {
                       console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
                       return response.data.data;
                       })
                     .catch(function (data) {
                      console.log(data);
                    });

                  return platform_data;
                 }
               };


       const createPlatformArray= (getPlData) => {

        // eslint-disable-next-line react/prop-types

          if (getPlData !== undefined) {

            usersData = getPlData.map((item) => {

                  return {
                            id: item.id,
                            platform: item.platform,
                            apiSignature: item.apiSignature,
                            environment: item.environment,
                            created_at: item.created_at, 
                        };
                      });
                    }
                  };

           return (
                   <>
                      {usersData && usersData.length > 0 ? (

                        <TableLayout
                         table_name="Platforms"
                         btn_name="Create Platform"
                         data={usersData}
                         fieldkeys={[
                         "id",
                         "Platform",
                         "apiSignature",
                         "environment",
                         "created_at",
                         "Edit",
                       ]}

                       editLink="appstore-cms"
                       deleteLink=""

                      />
                    ) : null}
               </>
             );
           };

     export default Platforms;
```

Once i fetch and process the api data, only then i want to call/allow the return () to execute. Till now I am able to perfectly fetch and process data from the api till the method: `createPlatformArray()` but after that the return () does not gets called or lets say it gets called before the api call.

Even after using async await I am not able to get the flow which I want. What i need is first fetch and process api data and only then render or execution of the return () mentioned at the bottom of the component Platforms.

Comment: That's not really how it works in React. The component will _always_ render (return HTML) first, and then you can fetch the data, and update the state, and re-render.

Comment: To go along with @Andy's comment, you'll need to save any fetched data into state, or trigger a state update, in order to trigger a rerender.

Comment: React is [_designed_ to flow a certain way](https://www.taniarascia.com/getting-started-with-react/). Trying to work against that is going to cause you misery.

Answer (score 0):

UsersData should be a state.

```
Const [usersData, setusersData] = useState([])
```

When you want to asign a new value to that state you need to use

```
setusersData(New value)
```

I guess thats enough because the useEffect seems to be right at first sight